# How do I use onFocusChangeListener with respect to a several subclassed fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, focus, android-fragmentactivity, lost-focus

I've got a `BaseQuestion` super class which extends a fragment. I've got several subclasses of this question, including `DropDownQuestion` and `EditTextQuestion`. I would like to do some pre-population and validation upon when a particular question has lost focus.

Originally, I had the onFocusChangeListener implemented by my `BaseQuestion` class, but it never got called, so I added `setFocusable` and `setFocusableInTouchMode` to a bunch of stuff in it, including the question's `LinearLayout`, and the actual view itself. But it still never got called. Then I realised, I can't add the logic in their, since it has no knowledge of the other questions. So I need to do it in my `FragmentActivity`.

So my actual question is: How do I know when the focus has been lost on a particular `View` in the `Fragment` whilst in the `FragmentActivity` and then act upon it?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Also, this is for a dynamic number of questions. So there may be quite a lot of questions.

**EDIT**

Bump

**EDIT2**
One more bump!